# Javascript Object , Making similar in C

Tags: javascript, c, object, char, int

In JavaScript i would usually do..

```
var myObject = { "Name" : "Liam", "Address" : "UK"};
```

How do i make something similar in C?

Preferably something of the structure

```
myObject { CHAR : INT}
```

Comment: you should learn c if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct myObj
{
 char* string;
 int num;
};
```

that's the most basic. you should learn c if you want to use this.

Comment: Generally, when someone asks a question about a specific language, answering the question about a different language doesn't fly.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an associative array. For example you could use one from the lighttpd project
[array.c](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/entry/trunk/src/array.c) [array.h](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/repository/entry/trunk/src/array.h)

What you need is data_integer structure.
Such an assitiative array is kinda like a javascript object the "key" is the the fields name, and the value, is the field's data.

Since JS objects are basically glorified dictionaries (maps) between field name to it's value, with some syntactic sugar - it's all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

C is *very* different from JavaScript, especially when it comes to strings and memory management.  Depending on what you want to do, the C equivalent could get very cumbersome.

If you know the max length of your string member, you could do

```
struct obj {
  char name[LENGTH];
  int num;
};

struct obj myObj;
...
strcpy(obj.name, "Some Name");
obj.num = 1;
```

C doesn't have a string data type as such; strings are represented as sequences of `char` values terminated by a 0, and stored as arrays of `char`.  The assignment operator `=` is not defined for array types, so you have to use library functions like `strcpy` to assign string values as above.

If you *don't* know the max length of your string member, you would do something like

```
struct obj {
  char *name;
  int num;
};

struct obj myObj;

myObj.name = malloc(length_of_string);
if (myObj.name)
{
  strcpy(myObj.name, "Some Name");
}
myObj.num = 1;
...
free(myObj.name);
```

In this case you have to allocate the memory for `myObj.name` manually using the `malloc` library call, and you have to deallocate it using the `free` library call.

If you want to store a sequence of that type, you'd do something like

```
struct obj myObjArray[NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS];
```

and do your assignments as

```
myObjArray[i].num = 1;
strcpy(myObjArray[i].name, "Some Name");
```